# Workflow status canceled if item is not created by owners

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

i have a workflow in SharePoint 2013 that starts when item is created in a list.
if the item is created by an owner the workflow runs perfectly. 
if the item is created by any other user, the workflow status will be canceled, and one of the owners should start it manually.

please help. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is a SharePoint designer workflow, attempt to use the impersonation step before running any of the steps of the workflow.

Comment: thanks man. i figured out later that the workflow is trying to edit items in the list and the editing had to be included in the impersonation step. Thanks anws.